# About using Phalcon4 and Phalcon3 with PHP8.0

Tags: php, phalcon

Do you agree with the recognition that you cannot use Phalcon4 and Phalcon3 with PHP8.0?

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  Phalcon 3 and 4 are both incompatible with PHP 8.0 and 8.1.

However, the Phalcon team are just a few weeks away from releaseing Phalcon 5 which is compatible with PHP 8.  We've been testing two of our products with Phalcon 5 (release candidate 2) and PHP 8.1 and our products are working well in testing.